# Transform a list with legacy data to a new list using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I'm getting from a legacy application the following data:

```
Id = 1
Name = Test 1

Id = 2
Name = Test 2#;10#;Test 3#;11#; Test 4#;12 // This simulates a multiple values field in legacy system
```

I want to transform in the following format, getting multiple values field above and tranform in records. The item with Id = 2 above have to generate 3 records

```
Id = 1
Name = Test 1

Id = 2
Name = Test 2

Id = 2
Name = Test 3

Id = 2
Name = Test 4
```

ie, what I want is to transform what is now comes in only one field with multiple values concatened with #; in a list with several records. Its possible using Linq ?

I try to resolve with the code bellow

```
var list = lista.Select(x => x.Name.Split(new string[] { "#;" }, System.StringSplitOptions.None)
.Where(xa => !int.TryParse(xa, out zeroValue))
.Select(xa => 
 new { 
      Id = x.Id, Name = xa
 })
).ToList();
```

This code retursn a List of two arrays, the first array with 1 element and the second with 3. The items inside the arrays are correct, but I would like only one list with all 4 items

Comment: 1) What have you tried?
2) Not sure what your filtering criteria would be.

Comment: Sorry, I posted without finishing my question, now its complete

Comment: Can you describe in words what you are trying to do instead of showing **find ten differences** pictures? Also show what you have tried, and how your result differs from expected

Comment: I try this

var list = lista.Select(x => x.Name.Split(new string[] { "#" }, System.StringSplitOptions.None)
    .Where(xa => !int.TryParse(xa, out valor))
    .Select(xa => 
     new { 
      Id = x.Id, Name = xa
     })
    ).ToList();

Wich returns a list of arrays. The legacy system stores multiple values ​​in one field and I want to transform into multiple records

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
var result=lista.SelectMany(
    a=>Regex.Split(x.Name,"#;\d+#;"),(a,b)=>new {id=a.id,name=b});
```